# error C3121: cannot change GUID for class 'GeoPoint'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, guid, visual-c++-6

Error messages on build/re-build

```
e:\aaamac\aaamac\aaamacmprod\debug\jjjjgeo.tlh(1220): error C3121: cannot change GUID for class 'GeoPoint'
e:\aaamac\aaamac\aaamacmprod\debug\jjjjmap.tlh(488) : see declaration of 'GeoPoint'
```

click on the top line took me to a line in a file "aaaageo.tlh

```
struct __declspec(uuid("c0f74d34-2802-11d4-a320-006008bf4bdf"))
GeoPoint;
// [ default ] interface IGeoPoint
```

click on the bottom line took me to a line in a file "aaaamap.tlh"

```
struct __declspec(uuid("dd0257b9-5c91-473e-8203-bd472f51c44b"))
GeoPoint
{
   double lat;
   double lon;
};
```

aaaageo.tlh and aaaamap.tlh are generated codes from tlb files that I have no control over.

This code compiled, built, and ran using VC++ 6.
This code failed to compile/build using nVS2010.

What goes wrong?  The tlh files are generated automatically so I cannot remove one of the GeoPoint entries using an editor.

Comment: Clearly the type library contains junk.  And yes, that might not have been detected by VC6.  Contact the component vendor for support.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this for a quick temporary fix. May be rename GeoPoint to Geopoint1 in #import ?

Comment: I tried exclude("GeoPoint") in one of the #import and it got over this problem for now. Program may not run properly, but at least I can compile and build and continue with the other projects downstream. Thanks.